# how do you set a value that is an observable in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```js
var vm = (function() {
      var selectedFoo = ko.observable(),
          foos = [
            { id: 1, fooName: 'fooName1', fooType: 'fooType1' },
            { id: 2, fooName: 'fooName2', fooType: 'fooType2' },
            { id: 3, fooName: 'fooName3', fooType: 'fooType3' },
          ];
    
      return {
        selectedFoo: selectedFoo,
        foos: foos
      };
    }());
            
            ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: foos, 
                   optionsText: 'fooName', 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select foo', 
                   value: selectedFoo"></select><br />
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

While above code works, how would set the initial value of the dropdown? Say you got an `id` value of `2` from an ajax call. How would you set the selected option based on the id?

I've looked in the for solutions but I only found adding a `optionsValue` but I need the member of the selected option as display

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All you would need to do is set selectedFoo's value to whatever value you get from that ajax call

Comment: @pglynn I only got an `id` from an ajax call. so setting `selectedFoo(2)` won't work. Or am I missing something? think you can show me how? for future reference

Comment: That is how you would hydrate the value of the select box. How you get that data (and when) is completely up to you.

Comment: Use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` to find the `foos` element with the matching `id` and then call `selectedFoo(foo)`.

Comment: @BoyPasmo What that "I need the member of the selected option as display" exactly means? Is soemthign wrong with my answer?

Comment: @BoyPasmo I've updated my answer hoping that a comment had let me know what you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misundertanding something. I've added the selected value in your snippet, and, if you change the id, the select list is updated correcty, and you still display what you want. I've added a bound textbox where you can type the `id` so that you can check it works as expected.

NOTE: just in case the comment below is what I couldn't understand from your question, I'm implementing a new writable computed observable that allos to use the whole object as selection.

```js
var vm = (function() {
      var foos = [
            { id: 1, fooName: 'fooName1', fooType: 'fooType1' },
            { id: 2, fooName: 'fooName2', fooType: 'fooType2' },
            { id: 3, fooName: 'fooName3', fooType: 'fooType3' },
          ],
          selectedFoo = ko.observable(),
          selectedFooId = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
              return selectedFoo() ? selectedFoo().id : null;
              },
            write: function(value) {
              var newSel = foos.find(function(f) {return f.id == value;});
              selectedFoo(newSel);
              }
          });
    
      return {
        selectedFooId: selectedFooId,
        selectedFoo: selectedFoo,
        foos: foos
      };
    }());
            
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: foos, 
                   optionsText: 'fooName', 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select foo', 
                   value: selectedFoo"></select><br />
<input type=text data-bind="value: selectedFooId, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: The issue now is that it's only the `id` that's selected, rather than the entire object.  I have the feeling that the OP gets, say, `2` back from the ajax call, then wants to still select the entire object, so you'd need to find the right one in the collection and set that in `selectedFoo`

Comment: @JamesThorpe I don't know if you're right, but you should have asked the OP if you or I am right. However, I've updated my answer in case you're right, so that the full foo is now the selected object. I'll let the OP know it. Thanks for explaining the downvote and give a chane to improve the answer..

Comment: FWIW I haven't voted either way - your answer is both useful but (in my eyes) not entirely what the OP is after

Comment: @JamesThorpe, that's even a greater reason to thank you. I've updated the answer according to your comment. Please, run it full screen and let me know if this is what you think the OP wants.Thank you!

Comment: Have an upvote :)  The only thing that would make it perfect now (just makes your demo a bit more slick) is if you used `valueUpdate: keyup` on the input binding so you don't need to blur the input to see a change :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks for your feddback!

Comment: @JotaBe oh so there's actually a `find()` method in javascript array. never knew about that. this is what I actually needed. thank you so much. Also thank you James for clarifying things out.

Comment: @BoyPasmo Beware of find. If it's not available in your browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), you can use lodash (https://lodash.com/docs#find) or underscore (http://underscorejs.org/#find) to avoid writing loops. There are more array improvements available in most browsers, but `find` is not impleemnted in most browsers.

Comment: @BoyPasmo You can also use filter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which is implemented in more browsers. For more info see this compatibility table: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: @JotaBe just a thought, how would you set the initial value of the dropdown upon first load?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing something... Why not `vm.SelectedFooId(555)`? Of course 555 would be the `id` received from an ajax call or whichever. Is there something I'm not taking into account?